# Vaadin ServerRPC Exceptionhandling

Tags: java, vaadin, gwt-rpc

I implemented a custom widget and it does calls via a ServerRPC implementation. This works all good.

I wanted to know how I should implement errorhandling, because I need the sent messages to be redelivered in case of an error.

I pretty much followed this chapter in the [book](https://vaadin.com/book/vaadin7/-/page/gwt.rpc.html).

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean exactly with the error handling?

Comment: Like in pure gwt rpc for instance with AsyncCallback, where a onFailure method exists. For instance if the message is not delivered due to network problems.